# MySql Table how to get all contacts?

Tags: mysql, join, outer-join

I have a MySQL query (I use phpmyadmin) and I know that a table shouldn't be created like this but I must have only one table for the project I worked on. This is my sql query.

```
 CREATE VIEW v_sugarcrm AS 
SELECT AC.id, A.id AS account_id, A.name, A.description, A.industry, A.phone_fax, A.phone_office, A.shipping_address_street, A.shipping_address_city, A.shipping_address_state, A.shipping_address_postalcode, A.shipping_address_country, C.id AS contact_id, C.first_name, SUBSTRING_INDEX(C.last_name, ' ', -1) as last_name,concat(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_name) as full_name, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(concat(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_name), ' ', 2), ' ', -1) as middle_name, C.title, C.department, C.phone_home, C.phone_mobile, C.phone_work, C.primary_address_street, C.primary_address_city, C.primary_address_state, C.primary_address_postalcode, C.primary_address_country, C.deleted, EA.email_address as email_account,
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(EA_C1.email_address), ',', 1), ',', -1) as email_2,
   If(length(GROUP_CONCAT(EA_C1.email_address)) - length(replace(GROUP_CONCAT(EA_C1.email_address), ',', ''))>=1,
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(EA_C1.email_address), ',', 2), ',', -1), NULL) as email_3,
   If(length(GROUP_CONCAT(EA_C1.email_address)) - length(replace(GROUP_CONCAT(EA_C1.email_address), ',', ''))>=2,
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(EA_C1.email_address), ',', 3), ',', -1), NULL) as email_4,
   If(length(GROUP_CONCAT(EA_C1.email_address)) - length(replace(GROUP_CONCAT(EA_C1.email_address), ',', ''))>=3,
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(EA_C1.email_address), ',', 4), ',', -1), NULL) as email_5,
EA_C.email_address as email_contact,
GROUP_CONCAT(EA_C1.email_address) as alt_email_contact
FROM ACCOUNTS A 
INNER JOIN ACCOUNTS_CONTACTS AS AC ON A.id = AC.account_id 
INNER JOIN CONTACTS AS C ON C.id = AC.contact_id 
LEFT JOIN EMAIL_ADDR_BEAN_REL AS ER ON ER.bean_id = A.id 
AND ER.bean_module = "Accounts" AND ER.primary_address =1 
LEFT JOIN EMAIL_ADDR_BEAN_REL AS ER_C ON ER_C.bean_id = C.id 
AND ER_C.bean_module = "Contacts" AND ER_C.primary_address =  1
LEFT JOIN EMAIL_ADDR_BEAN_REL AS ER_C1 ON ER_C1.bean_id = C.id and ER_C1.deleted !=1
AND ER_C1.primary_address !=1
LEFT JOIN EMAIL_ADDR_BEAN_REL AS ER_A1 ON ER_A1.bean_id = A.id AND ER_A1.deleted !=1 
and ER_A1.primary_address !=1 
LEFT JOIN EMAIL_ADDRESSES AS EA ON ER.email_address_id = EA.id
LEFT JOIN EMAIL_ADDRESSES AS EA_C ON ER_C.email_address_id = EA_C.id
LEFT JOIN EMAIL_ADDRESSES AS EA_C1 ON ER_C1.email_address_id = EA_C1.id
AND EA_C1.invalid_email !=1 AND EA_C1.opt_out !=1
LEFT JOIN EMAIL_ADDRESSES AS EA_A1 ON ER_A1.email_address_id = EA_A1.id 
AND EA_A1.invalid_email !=1 AND EA_A1.opt_out !=1
GROUP BY A.ID
```

Account_Contacts table
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUECA.png

My main issue revolves around the two inner joins I have at the top of the query, As of right now this query gives me all the info I need for both a contact and a company, however when there are multiple contacts associated with one company it only displays one contact and not both. I would like to know how I can change my query so it displays all contacts even if the information for the company is the same, the information for the contact should differ, and they should have different ids as well.

I really need help!

Comment: There is more than one table there.

Comment: Yes there are multiple but my main concern is with accounts, contacts, and account_contacts. I will paste a picture of the tables one moment.

Comment: Account table:http://i.stack.imgur.com/rK2lN.png

Comment: Contact Table: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XoX74.png

Comment: CREATE statements usually help more. (and, aw hell, GUIDs in a MySQL database).

Answer (score 0):

You are using GROUP BY A.ID. It will show only one record corresponding to that ID. So only one contact is displaying.
So you can use GROUP BY C.ID, A.ID

Comment: Alright but i want to display all contacts and their associated companies. A.id in this case is the company. So how would i make it so it shows ALL contacts and the company as well. even if there are duplicates of company info?

Comment: change column order in group by. GROUP BY C.EMAIL_ID, A.ID

Comment: Alright  I am grouping by AC.id now however it gives me a duplicate of one extra contact (the last one entered)  ?

Comment: i dont get a field called email_id?

Comment: @ChewyMasta if it helps the correct my answer, so others doesn't invest their time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive, but I think you might be able to simplify your query quite a bit (eliminating the multiple uses of `EMAIL_ADDR_BEAN_REL` AND `EMAIL_ADDRESSES`) with a more complicated join condition on the join to `EMAIL_ADDR_BEAN_REL`.

Something *similar to* the below fragment. I've changed the logic slightly, guessing at some possible errors or unnecessary conditions; GUID use hints that you might not need to know the "bean module":

```
...
FROM ACCOUNTS A 
   INNER JOIN ACCOUNTS_CONTACTS AS AC ON A.id = AC.account_id 
   INNER JOIN CONTACTS AS C ON C.id = AC.contact_id 
   LEFT JOIN EMAIL_ADDR_BEAN_REL AS ER 
       ON ER.bean_id IN (A.id, C.id) 
       AND (ER.primary_address = 1 OR ER.deleted != 1)
   LEFT JOIN EMAIL_ADDRESSES AS EA ON ER.email_address_id = EA.id
...
```

I suspect it would probably simplify all the stuff you are doing in the `SELECT` clause as well.